# Direct2D Zoom and Pan

Tags: delphi, direct2d

Been trying to put code together from samples to make a zoom/pan image with Direct2D but not really working well.

Basically the picture will drag across the window, but once i let go of the mouse it falls back to its original place, i want it to stay in the position it was dropped.

All the images will go outside the client size as well, so i want to pan to those areas also.

The zoom is still work in progress, but not having much luck.

This is where i am at so far:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
const
  ZoomFactor: array[Boolean] of Single = (0.9, 1.1);
begin
  if WheelDelta = 120 then
  begin
    if PtInRect(ClientRect, MousePos) then
    begin
      R.Left := Left + MousePos.X - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * MousePos.X);
      R.Top := Top + MousePos.Y - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * MousePos.Y);
      FRenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(R.Left,R.Top));
      //Invalidate;
    end;
  end;
  if WheelDelta = -120 then
  begin
   exit;
  end;
  Handled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDraging := True;
  OldPosX:=X;
  OldPosY:=Y;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  S1:='Position X: '+IntToStr(X)+' Position Y: '+IntToStr(Y);
  if FDraging and (OldPosX <> X) and (OldPosY <> Y) then
  begin
    NewPosX:=Left + X - OldPosX;
    NewPosY:=Top + Y - OldPosY;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDraging := False;
  CurrentPosX:=X - NewPosX;
  CurrentPosY:=Y - NewPosX;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  b0:=GetD2D1Bitmap(FRenderTarget, Caly_00);
  FRenderTarget.BeginDraw;
  try
    if FDraging then
    begin
      FRenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(NewPosX, NewPosY));
      FRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(b0, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
    end else begin
      FRenderTarget.SetTransform(TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(CurrentPosX, CurrentPosY));
      FRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(b0, nil, 1, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR, nil);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its create a Direct2D canvas and draw a bitmap, also you can pan and zoom the view.

```
unit D2DForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Direct2D, D2D1;

type
  TD2DForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    FZoom: D2D_SIZE_F;          // Zoom level
    FView: TD2DPoint2f;         // Transaltion
    FBitmap: ID2D1Bitmap;       // A bitmap
    FCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;   // The Direct2D canvas
    FDragging: Boolean;         // Dragging state
    FOldMousePos: TPoint;       // Previous mouse position
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
  end;

var
  D2DForm: TD2DForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TD2DForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FZoom := D2D1SizeF(1, 1);  // Zoom level, start from 1x
  FView := D2D1PointF(0, 0); // Translation
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FCanvas);
end;

// CreateWnd is called when the form is created
procedure TD2DForm.CreateWnd;
var
  LBitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  inherited;
  // TDirect2DCanvas.Create need a handle, so called from CreateWnd
  FCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Handle);

  // Load a bitmap
  LBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  LBitmap.LoadFromFile('c:\testb.bmp');   // Load your bitmap
  try
    FBitmap := FCanvas.CreateBitmap(LBitmap);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LBitmap);
  end;
end;

// WMPaint is called when need to repaint the window
// this will call our FormPaint()
procedure TD2DForm.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  LPaintStruct: TPaintStruct;
begin
  // This will render the canvas

  BeginPaint(Handle, LPaintStruct);
  try
    FCanvas.BeginDraw;
    try
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.EndDraw;
    end;
  finally
    EndPaint(Handle, LPaintStruct);
  end;
end;

// WMSize is called when resizing the window
procedure TD2DForm.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  // here we resize our canvas to the same size of the window
  if Assigned(FCanvas) then
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget(FCanvas.RenderTarget).Resize(
      D2D1SizeU(ClientWidth,       ClientHeight));

  inherited;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  FOldMousePos := Point(X, Y);
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
  begin
    // Translate the view
    // its depend from zoom level
    FView.X := FView.X + ((X - FOldMousePos.X) / FZoom.Width );
    FView.Y := FView.Y + ((Y - FOldMousePos.Y) / FZoom.Height);
    FOldMousePos := Point(X, Y);
    RePaint;
  end;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  // Update zoom level
  if WheelDelta > 0 then
  begin
    // Zoom in
    FZoom.Width  := FZoom.Width  * 1.1;
    FZoom.Height := FZoom.Height * 1.1;
  end
  else
  begin
    // Zoom Out
    FZoom.Width  := FZoom.Width  * 0.9;
    FZoom.Height := FZoom.Height * 0.9;
  end;
  Handled := True;
  RePaint;
end;

// Main painting routine
procedure TD2DForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LView: TD2DMatrix3x2F;
begin
  // Paint canvas
  with FCanvas do
  begin
    // Clear
    RenderTarget.Clear(D2D1ColorF(clBlack));

    // Create view matrix
    // we create a translation and zoom(scale) matrix
    // and combine them
    LView := TD2DMatrix3x2F.SetProduct(
      TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(FView),
      TD2DMatrix3x2F.Scale(FZoom, D2D1PointF(ClientWidth / 2, ClientHeight / 2)));

    // Set the view matrix
    RenderTarget.SetTransform(LView);

    // Draw the bitmap
    RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(FBitmap);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation also about what you have added

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort, this code works perfectly! Would it be possible for you to show this working with multiple bitmaps being loaded instead of 1? So the bitmaps load simultaneously next to each other and not overlapping.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/phaH1xYB not sure if this is the best way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This code can handle multiple bitmaps, test it :)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Direct2D, D2D1, StdCtrls, wincodec, ActiveX;

type
  TIntArray = array of Integer;
  TD2DForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    FZoom: D2D_SIZE_F;                // Zoom level
    FView: TD2DPoint2f;               // Transaltion
    FCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;         // The Direct2D canvas
    FBitmaps: array of ID2D1Bitmap;   // Bitmaps
    FDragging: Boolean;               // Dragging state
    FOldMousePos: TPoint;             // Previous mouse position
    FBitmapTable: array of TIntArray; // Table, each item contain index to a bitmap
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
    procedure WMEraseBkGnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkGnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  end;

var
  D2DForm: TD2DForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetD2D1Bitmap(RenderTarget: ID2D1RenderTarget; imgPath: string): ID2D1Bitmap;
var
  iWicFactory: IWICImagingFactory;
  iWICDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder;
  iWICFrameDecode: IWICBitmapFrameDecode;
  iFormatConverter: IWICFormatConverter;
begin
  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, iWicFactory);
  iWicFactory.CreateDecoderFromFilename(PWideChar(imgPath), GUID_NULL, GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, iWICDecoder);
  iWicDecoder.GetFrame(0, iWICFrameDecode);
  iWicFactory.CreateFormatConverter(iFormatConverter);
  iFormatConverter.Initialize(iWICFrameDecode, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, nil, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
  RenderTarget.CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(iFormatConverter, nil, Result);
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FZoom := D2D1SizeF(1, 1);  // Zoom level, start from 1x
  FView := D2D1PointF(0, 0); // Translation
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(FCanvas);
end;

// CreateWnd is called when the form is created
procedure TD2DForm.CreateWnd;
var
  LIndexX: Integer;
  LIndexY: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  // TDirect2DCanvas.Create need a handle, so called from CreateWnd
  FCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(Handle);

  // Load bitmaps
  SetLength(FBitmaps, 3); // you can load more, if you want
  FBitmaps[0] := GetD2D1Bitmap(FCanvas.RenderTarget, 'c:\testb.bmp');
  FBitmaps[1] := GetD2D1Bitmap(FCanvas.RenderTarget, 'c:\bitmap.bmp');
  FBitmaps[2] := GetD2D1Bitmap(FCanvas.RenderTarget, 'c:\test.bmp');

  // Create a 4 x 3 sized table, you can increase the size, if you want
  SetLength(FBitmapTable, 4);
  for LIndexY := 0 to Length(FBitmapTable) - 1 do
  begin
    SetLength(FBitmapTable[LIndexY], 3);
    for LIndexX := 0 to Length(FBitmapTable[LIndexY]) - 1 do
      FBitmapTable[LIndexY, LIndexX] := Random( Length(FBitmaps) ); // set bitmap index, to each table item
  end;
end;

// WMPaint is called when need to repaint the window
// this will call our FormPaint()
procedure TD2DForm.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
var
  LPaintStruct: TPaintStruct;
begin
  // This will render the canvas

  BeginPaint(Handle, LPaintStruct);
  try
    FCanvas.BeginDraw;
    try
      Paint;
    finally
      FCanvas.EndDraw;
    end;
  finally
    EndPaint(Handle, LPaintStruct);
  end;
end;

// WMSize is called when resizing the window
procedure TD2DForm.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
begin
  // here we resize the our canvas too
  if Assigned(FCanvas) then
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget(FCanvas.RenderTarget).Resize(D2D1SizeU(ClientWidth, ClientHeight));

  inherited;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.WMEraseBkGnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkGnd);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  FOldMousePos := Point(X, Y);
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
  begin
    // Translate the view
    // its depend from zoom level
    FView.X := FView.X + ((X - FOldMousePos.X) / FZoom.Width );
    FView.Y := FView.Y + ((Y - FOldMousePos.Y) / FZoom.Height);
    FOldMousePos := Point(X, Y);
    RePaint;
  end;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
end;

procedure TD2DForm.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  // Update zoom level
  if WheelDelta > 0 then
  begin
    // Zoom in
    FZoom.Width  := FZoom.Width  * 1.1;
    FZoom.Height := FZoom.Height * 1.1;
  end
  else
  begin
    // Zoom Out
    FZoom.Width  := FZoom.Width  * 0.9;
    FZoom.Height := FZoom.Height * 0.9;
  end;
  Handled := True;
  RePaint;
end;

// Main painting routine
procedure TD2DForm.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  LSize: TD2DSizeF;
  LRect: TD2D1RectF;
  LView: TD2DMatrix3x2F;
  LIndexX: Integer;
  LIndexY: Integer;
  LBitmap: ID2D1Bitmap;
  LMaxHeight: Single;
begin
  // Paint canvas
  with FCanvas do
  begin
    // Clear
    RenderTarget.Clear(D2D1ColorF(clBlack));

    // Create view matrix
    // we create a translation and zoom(scale) matrix
    // and combine them
    LView := TD2DMatrix3x2F.SetProduct(
      TD2DMatrix3x2F.Translation(FView),
      TD2DMatrix3x2F.Scale(FZoom, D2D1PointF(ClientWidth / 2, ClientHeight / 2)));

    // Set the view matrix
    RenderTarget.SetTransform(LView);

    // Draw the bitmap table
    LRect.Left := 0; LRect.Top := 0;
    for LIndexY := 0 to Length(FBitmapTable) - 1 do
    begin
      LMaxHeight := 0;
      for LIndexX := 0 to Length(FBitmapTable[LIndexY]) - 1 do
      begin
        // Get bitmap to draw
        LBitmap := FBitmaps[ FBitmapTable[LIndexY, LIndexX] ];

        // Get Bitmap Size
        LBitmap.GetSize(LSize);

        // Calc destination rect
        LRect.Right  := LRect.Left + LSize.Width;
        LRect.Bottom := LRect.Top  + LSize.Height;

        // Draw
        RenderTarget.DrawBitmap(LBitmap, @LRect);

        // Increment left position
        LRect.Left   := LRect.Left + LSize.Width;

        // Calc max bitmap height in this row
        if LSize.Height > LMaxHeight then
          LMaxHeight := LSize.Height;
      end;
      LRect.Left := 0;
      LRect.Top  := LRect.Top + LMaxHeight;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Any idea why there is a slight black line (background colour) between the bitmaps when zooming in and out? On first load, the lines aren't there.

Comment: I dont no why, i test it on two pc and i cant see black lines. May be some filtering or rounding error. Try to disable filtering, or make a minimal overlap between images.